# LibreOffice Draw 7.3 Navigator Drag&Drop broken or am I an idiot

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

I know there is a LibreOffice Support but I can't seem to figure out how to create an account since they don't send password reset mails or account creation mails and I feel stupid for asking this here.

So I'm working with LibreOffice Draw to create a map of our companies building and where which PC / Network Patch / Printer is located. Now I'm worked for quite some days already just on the Ground level. The program keeps crashing when I group items and sometimes items disappear. This is to give you an idea on how irritated / annoyed I am any what made me create this in the first place.

Every so often I rearranged the items like Patch A.1 & A.2 - Patch A.23 & A.24 but on each crash it normally just shuffles everything back in the order I created the items.

Now I tried to create a new .odg file and copy what I got over, however in the new file I cannot rearrange anything via Draw & Drop in the Navigator (F5) while it still works in the old file.

Am I missing a setting or am I just stupid that it's a setting that is too well hidden and easy to overlook? Would post this on the LibreOffice page but it doesn't send me any mails so I cannot even access it. :C

Comment: Likely a bug.  You can [search for LibreOffice Draw bugs here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=navigator%7Cdrag%7Cdrop%7Cgroup%20component%3ADraw).  You can also file bug reports on that site. But as you mention, new account registrations may take some patience. Personally, I prefer to use [draw.io](https://app.diagrams.net).  Just my 2c.

Comment: @leeharvey1 I've never heard of draw.io but it seems like a nice option. I will try and keep it in mind next time I need something like this. ;)